# "Welcome to nginx" and "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" default pages

Tags: proxy, nginx, gitlab, owncloud

So I have a physical server set up in my home with Proxmox VE 5.3 as the main OS. I have 4 VMs installed in Proxmox:

- **Nginx** (installed on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM)
- **Discourse** (installed on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM), set up for HTTP, with plans to setup HTTPS
- **GitLab** (installed on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM), set up for HTTP, with plans to setup HTTPS
- **ownCloud** (installed on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM), set up for HTTPS

The idea of this setup is for Nginx to reverse proxy the other 3 VMs. Unfortunately I seem to be having a lot of difficulty with this. Let me show what I'm getting in my browser in the tables below:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    VM     |                URL                                    |                         What I get back in the Browser                             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Discourse | http://discourse.myreserveddns.com                    | "Welcome to nginx!" default page                                                   |
| GitLab    | http://git.myreserveddns.com                          | Redirects to http://git.myreserveddns.com/users/sign_in, the page I expect to see. |
| ownCloud  | http://oc.myreserveddns.com                           | Redirects to https://oc.myreserveddns.com                                          |
| ownCloud  | https://oc.myreserveddns.com                          | "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page"                                                      |
| ownCloud  | https://oc.myreserveddns.com/owncloud/index.php/login | I get the ownCloud login page, as I expect to see.                                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So basically GitLab is redirecting as expected. ownCloud I can get to a login page with the full URL, but I would really like for simple URLs like http://oc.myreserveddns.com and https://oc.myreserveddns.com to route to the login URL and Discourse I can only get the "Welcome to nginx!" default page. For Discourse, I should mention that I have gotten the proper Discourse page to come up with http://discourse.myreserveddns.com, but then after I tested the Private IP in a browser, all I get is the Nginx default page.

Anyways here are my Nginx conf files in /etc/nginx/sites-available (and yes, all include symbolic links to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled):

**discourse.conf**

```
server {
# The IP that you forwarded in your router (nginx proxy)
  listen 192.168.1.101:80; listen [::]:80;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
 server_name discourse.myreserveddns.com;

# The internal IP of the VM that hosts your Apache config
 set $upstream 192.168.1.104;

 location / {

 proxy_pass_header Authorization;
 proxy_pass http://unix:/var/discourse/shared/standalone/nginx.http.sock:;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Connection "";
 proxy_buffering off;
 client_max_body_size 0;
 proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
 proxy_redirect off;

 }
}
```

**gitlab.conf**
(would include the code, but I'm being told the post looks like spam, and its less important than the other CONF files to show)

**owncloud.conf**

```
server {
# The IP that you forwarded in your router (nginx proxy)
  listen 192.168.0.101:443 ssl;

# SSL config
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/owncloud.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/owncloud.key;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
 server_name oc;

# The internal IP of the VM that hosts your Apache config
 set $upstream 192.168.0.102;

 location / {

 proxy_pass_header Authorization;
 proxy_pass https://$upstream;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Connection "";
 proxy_buffering off;
 client_max_body_size 0;
 proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
 proxy_redirect off;

 }
}
```

So I guess I have two main questions:

1. How come I'm getting the "Welcome to nginx!" and "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" default pages? Where do I find these "default" pages in Nginx?

   - The default Apache page is very odd for ownCloud. Its running Apache for its SSL, so the default page for it could be on the ownCloud VM. Meanwhile Discourse does not have Nginx installed on it at all!
2. Can I redirect from one link to another with Nginx? For example, could I redirect from https://oc.myreserveddns.com to https://oc.myreserveddns.com/owncloud/index.php/login ?

Comment: UPDATE: So, I think I've solved part of my problem, thanks to someone on Reddit where I've asked the same questions: in particular my question about ownCloud. I'll post my response here: https://www.reddit.com/r/nginx/comments/bq6g77/welcome_to_nginx_and_apache2_ubuntu_default_page/eoa8kan?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x ... Of course, as I mentioned in the Reddit post, I seriously doubt I can just update the Nginx conf file on the Nginx VM to do an HTML redirect, since Discourse's link is supposed to already be "discourse.myreserveddns.com". Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: ANOTHER UPDATE: Discourse HTTP and GitLab HTTP are both working now, but GitLab is giving me a "500" Error. See https://forum.gitlab.com/t/500-error-upon-gitlab-login/26672